# How to detect whether file uploaded by FTP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, detect

I have a client who uploads an XML file to a directory on my server using a third party script over which I have no control. Upon upload the file gets processed by a php script.

I have a cronjob which checks the dir every hour to see whether a file has been uploaded but if the upload takes place at, say, 3:01pm it won't be processed until 4:00pm. My host forbids running a cronjob more frequently than once per hour.

Is there a way to detect and advise immmediately upon a file arriving?

Comment: decrease the interval of the cron. if the task in cron is heavy, create other cron. I cannnot think of anything else :)

Comment: Can you provide more info m, How the file is uploded thru teh server?Is he using ftp or ..?

Comment: try torun a bash script that run a script who check it , you can run it in backgroudn redirecting input output with: ./checker.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2> &  , And in checker.sh loop and sleep , and check if fiekl exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a file checker.sh , and run it in background ./checker.sh /dev/null 2>&1  & , or run it in screen

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=0
while [  $COUNTER -lt 99999 ]; do

if [ -f "/path/to/your/file" ]; then
    #do action here ,run a  script a program etc #the file is there
fi

sleep 5
let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 

done
```

Comment: This is the solution I went for but in php. The cron job runs every hour and sleeps for 60 seconds in a 'for' loop.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, it is possible to detect a file upload and perform an immediate action. However, this is not what I would call a "simple" solution. You would want to set up some sort of daemon so that you can [run PHP continually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427892/run-php-script-continuously) (or use a different language entirely to monitor for the file).

The simple solution is to lower your cron interval, and then just add some kind of anti-stacking mechanic (like a lockfile) to ensure your script doesn't execute if it's already running.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Linux you could look at the inotifywait command which is part of the inotify-tools package. This can be set up to wait until a file is created in a particular directory as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
inotifywait -e create /home/myuser/upload_dir/ && php /home/myuser/scripts/process_file.php
done
```

Comment: I got 'make install permission denied' when trying to install inotify. I'm on a shared Unix server which is perhaps why.